# How to plot a dendrogram on top of a heatmap of distance matrix

Tags: matlab

If I have a distance matrix, say, from the function pdist.
Now I want to plot a heatmap of this distance matrix with its rows and labels reordered so that a dendrogram on top of the heatmap/on one side of it shows the hierarchical structure/clustering of the distance matrix.

Note: I'm not using clustergram() to cluster the raw data. Here I only have the distance matrix.

Matlab dendrogram() function only plots a tree while HeatMap function only plots a heatmap.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after a year: Use HeatMap to plot the heatmap part of the distance matrix. And then plot the dendrogram separately and assemble them together using an image editor. Unfortunately there's no way to directly plot the whole thing yet.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
subplot(2,1,1); dendrogram(...);
subplot(2,1,2); heatmap(...);
```